# Ruby rconomic gem issue: SSL connect certificate verify fail

Tags: ruby, soap, openssl, rubygems, certificate

I'm trying to utilize a gem to access my accounting site, e-conomic, via Ruby.
Gem (rconomic): https://github.com/substancelab/rconomic

The code I've used is below (where I've replaced the private app ID and the access ID with the relevant IDs):

```
Dir.chdir 'C:\Ruby22\bin'

require 'rconomic'

economic = Economic::Session.new
economic.connect_with_token 'the_private_app_id', 'the_access_id_you_got_from_the_grant'
```

However, when I run the code I receive the following error message:

> C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/httpi-2.4.2/lib/httpi/adapter/net_http.rb:51:in 'rescue in request': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (HTTPI::SSLError)
>
> from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/httpi-2.4.2/lib/httpi/adapter/net_http.rb:33:in 'request'
>       from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/httpi-2.4.2/lib/httpi.rb:161:in `request'
>       from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/httpi-2.4.2/lib/httpi.rb:133:in 'post'
>       from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/operation.rb:94:in 'block in call_with_logging'
>       from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/request_logger.rb:12:in 'call'
>       from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/request_logger.rb:12:in 'log'
>       from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/operation.rb:94:in 'call_with_logging'
>       from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/operation.rb:54:in 'call'
>       from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/client.rb:36:in 'call'
>       from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rconomic-0.5.2/lib/economic/endpoint.rb:74:in 'request'
>       from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rconomic-0.5.2/lib/economic/endpoint.rb:20:in 'call'
>       from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rconomic-0.5.2/lib/economic/session.rb:22:in 'connect_with_token'
>       from C:/Ruby22/bin/rconomic_test.rb:8:in ''

Any ideas as to what would be causing this?
- I have tried updating my rubygems
- I am running on Windows 7 with Ruby 2.2.6

I'm a bit of a novice in Ruby, but I would really appreciate any help on this!

Best,
Martin

Comment: Have you created the right token? I don't see any magic here happening or any Ruby related issues, it just cannot connect with the details you're providing. Double check them please.

Comment: Hmm I have checked multiple times - and checked also with other access methods than the tokens (i.e. username and pass), still getting same error.
I'm wondering if it relates to my Ruby version and/or that I lack e.g. an openssl gem or something along those lines - though I'm not sure

Comment: How did you install Ruby ? rvm/rbenv ? Have your tried re-installing openSSL ?

Comment: I used the https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ Windows Ruby 2.2.6. I don't think I was asked to install openSSL as part of the installation. Should I install this separately somehow?

Comment: I have tried installing the openssl gem, though it says that it requires Ruby 2.3.0 or above. But I just wonder if this can really be correct that I need to upgrade vs. the 2.2.0 (which is the recommended version on the windows installer page)

Comment: It seems I now get a different error:

`connect': An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. - SSL_connect (Errno::ECONNRESET)

Any ideas?